# How call a function method passing through it different IDs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a counter function that can be applied to many ids. It means I want to pass through it different IDs to execute same action.

Something like that, but it doesn't work:

```
<a href="#" onclick="update_counter_dynamically(count_1)">+1 Counter</a>

<div id="count_1" class="column">0</div>

<a href="#" onclick="update_counter_dynamically(count_2)">+1 Counter</a>

<div id="count_2" class="column">0</div>

function update_counter_dynamically(my_id){
    var actual_value = $('#'+my_id);
    var num = parseInt(actual_value.text());
    actual_value.text(num+1); 
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Try changing `onclick="update_counter_dynamically(count_1)"` to `onclick="update_counter_dynamically('count_1');"` ? *Single quotes around the ID*

Comment: No error message, It wasn't working! But changing to 'count_1' solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function calls are flawed - you need to pass in strings for the ids, but you are passing it (undefined) variables. Instead, try:

```
<a href="#" onclick="update_counter_dynamically('count_1')">+1 Counter</a>
```

and

```
<a href="#" onclick="update_counter_dynamically('count_2')">+1 Counter</a>
```

Note that `count_1` is now passed as a string using single quotes. This allows us to define a string within the onClick= string.

Credit to @NewToJS for spotting the flaw in comments

Comment: I posted this as a comment as it's hardly worth posting as a answer.

Comment: Yeah, but it ruins our nice list of New Questions to see one with 0 answers :p

Comment: You mean you want to get your points up :p It's cool. Since you went into more details I will +1 you and it's also nice to see you did add Credits in ;)

Comment: Haha yes, it was also a shameless grab for rep! I will not deny that, but I will try sugarcoat it with the previous justification :p